# Marketing Cloud Connect: Limiting the number of synchronized Person Accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, person-accounts, contactbuilder

We're using using person accounts which populate both the Account and Contact synchronized data extensions. We want to limit the number of contacts that are being synchronized with the connect to exclude anonymized customers.

In Marketing Cloud in Contact Builder inside the Data Sources tab we're able to configure the synchronization and specify a flag based on which records are being collected in Marketing Cloud.

Where should this boolean value be located if we want to stop synchronizing an entire Person Account? Should it be on the account or the contact object?

I'm unable to test this by adding a boolean field to any object, so I would appreciate if someone with more experience with this setup could share the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add that field to the contact. With PersonAccounts enabled the field will also appear at the Account configuration with __pc at the end.

Example, where field is called "flag":
Contact: flag__c
Account: flag__pc

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Didn't know that fields from contacts get replicated to the account with this suffix.

Comment: You are welcome :)